# How do I handle catching errors in multiple places in Angular stream?

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, rxjs

right now I am trying to make sure I am handling errors correctly in a stream that first gets the id of a group, and then uses that group id to get profile information.

I need it so it's obvious which step is causing the error -- either the get groupId or the get profile info.

Right now I have something like this, but I am unsure if this is correct.

```
this.groupRepository
    .getUserGroup()
    .pipe(mergeMap(group) => {
        return this.profileRepository.getAllProfiles(group.id)
    })
    .subscribe(
        (res) => {
            // doing things in here to set the groups and profiles
        },
        (error) => {
            this.error = error;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Above is right if when `getUserGroup` will throw an error then `getAllProfiles` call will not be made. If you want to continue stream when an error occurs at any point then you can use `catchError` operator https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly.

Errors from both methods would end up in `(error) => {...}` method.

Small tests to play with:

```
of('A', 'B', 'C').pipe(mergeMap(letter => {
  return of('E', 'F', 'G');
})).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Returns: 'E', 'F', 'G', 'E', 'F', 'G'

With second method throws:

```
of('A', 'B', 'C').pipe(mergeMap(letter => {
  return throwError('bad');
})).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Returns: "bad"

With first method throws:

```
throwError('bad').pipe(mergeMap(letter => {
  return of('E', 'F', 'G');
})).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

Returns: "bad"